# Calculate yaw angle with different device orientation on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, sensors, quaternions, core-motion

In my app I need to display a horizontal line on the screen, so I've decided to turn to `CMMotionManager`. Here's my code, it's quite straightforward:

```
    if ([_motionManager isDeviceMotionAvailable]) {
        if ([_motionManager isDeviceMotionActive] == NO) {
            [_motionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:0.1];
            [_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error){
                CMQuaternion quat = _motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
                double yaw = asin(2*(quat.x*quat.z - quat.w*quat.y));
                // drawing line stuff.
            }];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Motion not avaliable!");;
    }
```

Eveything works fine when I put my phone in upward portrait mode. But since the `asin` method gives me only a number in range of (-pi/2,+pi/2), I can't draw a perfectly horizontal line if I hold my phone in landscape mode, or upside-down portrait mode, the line just stuck at angle of around -pi/2 or pi/2, and won't keep rotating.

So, how can I fix this, is there any more general way to handle quaternion? Thanks in advance!